# Button related issue:Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am facing this issue in Android. 
01-30 20:32:57.415 24227-24227/edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher, PID: 24227
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher/edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher.VCipherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at edu.gatech.seclass.vcipher.VCipherActivity.onCreate(VCipherActivity.java:48)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6998)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
        ----------------------------------------------
        It seems I am having some issue related to my button. But my button reference is not null but still I am getting this issue.

---

```
Please help me in resolving this.I am stucked in my android development due to this issue. Not able to resolve it.Help is very much appreciated.

Thanks
```

Comment: I think your button is really have null value. First suggestion is to clean and rebuild the project. If nothing happened, then please check if the id btn is under the layout activity_vcipher.

Comment: I have added my XML tree above. Can you please tell me what is the problem? I am new to this Android Studio so not able to figure out .

Comment: Where is your XML code? I can't see it @user3624146

Answer (score 1):

You will have null right there since your id on xml is android:id="@+id/button" not btn.
You have to change

```
final android.widget.Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

to

```
final android.widget.Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally my app is running. Thanks a ton